# How can I add external jar files to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, selenium3

I'm trying to add external jar files into eclipse and I don't seem to be able to. Can anyone help me out here? Clicking 'Apply' or 'Apply and Close' does nothing.

I'm using selenium 3 and the latest version of eclipse (oxygen - 4.7.0)

Please see image below: [adding jar files to eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTTPT.png)

Comment: Are you adding it as Jars or external jars?

Comment: Hi sirandy, I'm adding as external jar